# My form has two submit buttons for two decisions. Should it be one form or two?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, forms, coding-style

I want to know which decision my user chooses.

**Method 1**

[image: Method 1]

*HTML*

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Accept" name="decision" />
    <input type="submit" value="Decline" name="decision" />
</form>
```

*VB.NET*

```
If Decision = "Accept" Then
    ' Do this
ElseIf Decision = "Decline" Then
    ' Do that
End If
```

**Method 2**

[image: Method 2]

*HTML*

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="decision" value="true" />
    <input type="submit" value="Accept" />
</form>

<form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="decision" value="false" />
    <input type="submit" value="Decline" />
</form>
```

*VB.NET*

```
If Decision Then
    ' Do this
Else
    ' Do that
End If
```

Is there any real difference? Which would you go with and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are valid, however I would personally go with the first.

My reasons for doing so is that the markup is a little cleaner.  The forms purpose is for the user to make a decision and these elements IMO should be grouped together, for example a form called `frmDecision`.

The second reason is the code in the second example is ambigious.

For instance, in the code behind

```
 If Decision Then
```

Reads if Decision is equal to true, that necessary does not indicate `Accept` or `Decline`.  Also passing a parameter back to the server named Decision with a true or false value is a little flakey.

I find the first example cleaner, although you could use a resource file so you don't have to use magic strings.

Answer (score 0):

Case #1 is not scalable. When number of choices will grow it will be hard to manage. And not clean separation between actions, that might be useful when you call them via AJAX. Case #2 is redundant. I prefer third way. At first I have name selector attribute (I have converted it from C#, so not sure that it works properly):

```
Imports System
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Mvc
Imports System.Reflection

Namespace MySpace
    <AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple := False, Inherited := True)> _
    Public Class SubmitActionAttribute
        Inherits System.Web.Mvc.ActionNameSelectorAttribute
        #Region "-- Constants -----------------------------------------------------------------------"
        Friend Const ACTION_PREFIX As String = "action:"
        Private Const ROUTE_ACTION As String = "action"
        #End Region

        Private _Name As String = Nothing
        Public ReadOnly Property Name() As String
            Get
                Return _Name
            End Get
        End Property

        Public Overrides Function IsValidName(controllerContext As ControllerContext, actionName As String, methodInfo As MethodInfo) As Boolean
            Dim name As String = If(_Name, methodInfo.Name)

            Dim key As String = String.Concat(SubmitActionAttribute.ACTION_PREFIX, name)
            Dim value As ValueProviderResult = controllerContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue(key)
            If value IsNot Nothing Then
                controllerContext.RouteData.Values(SubmitActionAttribute.ROUTE_ACTION) = name
                Return True
            End If

            Return False
        End Function

        Public Sub New(name As String)
            _Name = name
        End Sub


        Public Sub New()
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Then I add this attribute to controller's action

```
    <SubmitAction("Accept")> _
    Public Function AcceptSmth() As ActionResult

    End Function
```

And use in HTML:

```
<input type="submit" value="Any value for caption" name="action:Accept" />
```

Comment: this is a VB solution not C#.  Secondly, I believe the solution you provided is overkill for the situation of passing a value back to the server.

Comment: I agree with Darren on all counts.

Comment: I hope this is not a problem to translate c# to vb, there is a lot of convertors available (f.e. http://converter.telerik.com/). As for overkill - I didn'g get, where do you find it? It is the same pair name+value in ValueProvider as in the sample #1, but with more clean separation of actions that is much more capable for AJAX calls, f.e. You can just call Accept/Decline actions, not a some complex action with a lot of conditions inside, passing redundant options to it (such as "decision"), etc. I hope you understand that there might be more than two choices and case #1 becomes a...

Comment: So if it is not a problem to convert C# to vb why didn't you?  Try posting a vb answer to a question marked C# and see what happens.

Comment: So this is a kind of revenge :) Sorry, I'm newbie here and never had a problem when somebody give me a code snippet in VB. Didn't know that this is a problem here. Hoped that we will discuss that case #1 is not scalable, case #2 is redundant, not the language holywars. I didn't converted because think that it will be better for TC to have both versions (working and converted), because I can't guarantee that converted will work. It seems I have to learn a lot about rules here...

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with the first.  The vb code you provided should look more like this

```
Private Sub Accept_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Accept.Click
    'do this
End Sub

Private Sub Decline_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Decline.Click
    'do that
End Sub
```

or if there is common code between the two

```
Private Sub Accept_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Accept.Click
    doThisOrThat(True)
End Sub

Private Sub Decline_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Decline.Click
    doThisOrThat(False)
End Sub

Private Sub doThisOrThat(decision As Boolean)
    If decision Then
        'do this
    Else
        'do that
    End If
End Sub
```